# How to test server's peak draw on electrical amperage?

Tags: electrical-power

I'm moving my server to a co-location center and they'r not concerned with the actual wattage, which is what I've tracked, but they are very concerned with the peak amperage. They charge by the amps made available to the machine. Is there some industry standard way I can test that? The person I spoke with in the data center is a sales guys, so he's not sure of the technical aspects that he's asking me about.

If there's a software solution, my system is an HP DL580 G7 running centos 7.

**What I've tried:**

I have a UPS on it now that gives wattage outputs which bounce all over the place. The highest I've seen is 800 watts, so my guess is 800watts/120volts should be six and two thirds amps. Do I provision 7 amps? Doesn't sound very precise.

Powerstat says "Device does not have any RAPL domains, cannot power measure power usage." so I don't think it's compatible with my system.

Please let me know what the industry standards for this are.

Comment: 7 amps is quite a lot, actually, but the safest course is to find the rated energy consumption of the power supply in Watts from the manufacturer's data and assume peak current draw will be based on that. You may never reach that current draw, but you'll have it if you need it. This is unless they have burst pricing, in which case looking to the UPS is probably your best bet.

Comment: I mean, it sure seems likely that the theoretically maximum amperage should be somewhat related to the total max capacity of your power supply(s).

Comment: @Zoredache and Harry Johnson. There are 4 1200 watt PSU's on this machine, but I don't think it's conceivable that it would draw 40 amps. Even 20 amps is ridiculous. I've had it running on a 1500 Volt-Amp UPS without problems for a little over 2 years.